# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why this function call is giving me the above error?

```
count=0
def returncall():
  for i,j in enumerate(range(count,count+3),0):
    print i,j
  return j
count=returncall
print count()
```

Comment: I don't even know where to start, there's to many fundamental mistakes. Why it's simultaneously tagged as 2.x and 3.x?

Comment: `j` is not in the scope of your for loop therefore `j` is not defined. You aren't passing in `count` so in your function, `count` is undefined.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Suggestion for where to start: a constructive comment.

Comment: `count` is a function. What should adding `3` to it do?

Comment: We should start with basics, what are you trying to achieve? Edit your question and gives us a description of what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
for i,j in enumerate(range(count,count+3),0):
```

`count` is another name for `returncall` because you have done `count = returncall`. `returncall` is a function; in fact, it's the very function that statement is in. You can't add an integer to a function (`count+3`) because that is meaningless.

I don't really understand what you're attempting to do here, so can't really offer further advice. But that's what the error message means.